# Issue loading data sets for kNN algorithm - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, knn

I have applied the KNN algorithm for classifying handwritten digits. the digits are in vector format initially 8*8, and stretched to form a vector 1*64 with each set of data having a class code of 0..9.

As far as I can tell my code should work in theory but this is my first time experimenting with this algorithm. My issue stems when I am trying to input my data sets through my algorithm I am thrown an error on the lines highlighted in my code. The training dataset can be found [**here**](http://www.cwa.mdx.ac.uk/csd3939/coursework/cw2DataSet1.csv) and the validation set [**here**](http://www.cwa.mdx.ac.uk/csd3939/coursework/cw2DataSet2.csv). I have also left in my previous working main function if it helps.

**ImageMatrix.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class ImageMatrix {
    private int[] data;
    private int classCode;

public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
    assert data.length == 64; //maximum array length of 64
    this.data = data;
    this.classCode = classCode;
}

    public String toString() {
        return "Class Code: " + classCode + " Data :" + Arrays.toString(data) + "\n"; //outputs readable
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

}
```

**ImageMatrixDB.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ImageMatrixDB implements Iterable<ImageMatrix> {
    private List<ImageMatrix> list = new ArrayList<ImageMatrix>();

    public ImageMatrixDB load(String f) throws IOException {
        try (
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int lastComma = line.lastIndexOf(',');
                int classCode = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1 + lastComma));
                int[] data = Arrays.stream(line.substring(0, lastComma).split(","))
                                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                   .toArray();
                ImageMatrix matrix = new ImageMatrix(data, classCode);
                list.add(matrix);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void printResults(){ //output results 
        for(ImageMatrix matrix: list){
            System.out.println(matrix);
        }
    }


    public Iterator<ImageMatrix> iterator() {
        return this.list.iterator();
    }

    /// kNN implementation ///
    public static int distance(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += (a[i] - b[i]) * (a[i] - b[i]);
        }
        return (int)Math.sqrt(sum); //Euclidean sqrt of the sum 
    }


    public static int classify(List<ImageMatrix> trainingSet, int[] curData) {
        int label = 0, bestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(ImageMatrix matrix: trainingSet) {
            int dist = distance(matrix.getData(), curData);
            if(dist < bestDistance) {
                bestDistance = dist;
                curData = matrix.getData();
            }
        }
        return label;
    }


    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        ImageMatrixDB i = new ImageMatrixDB();
        List<ImageMatrix> trainingSet = i.load("cw2DataSet1.csv"); // << ERROR HERE
        List<ImageMatrix> validationSet = i.load("cw2DataSet2.csv"); //<< ERROR HERE
        int numCorrect = 0;
        for(ImageMatrix matrix:validationSet) {
            if(classify(trainingSet, matrix.getData()) == matrix.getClassCode()) numCorrect++;
        }
        System.out.println("Accuracy: " + (double)numCorrect / validationSet.size() * 100 + "%");
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////

    // Previous working dataset Load //
 /*   public static void main(String[] args){
        ImageMatrixDB i = new ImageMatrixDB();
        try{
            i.load("cw2DataSet1.csv"); 
            i.printResults();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } */

}
```

EDIT///

Error message currently says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageMatrixDB to List<ImageMatrix>
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageMatrixDB to List<ImageMatrix>
    at ImageMatrixDB.main(ImageMatrixDB.java:64)
```

But I have been thrown other errors while testing.

Comment: The clue is in the error, you are trying to assign an ImageMatrixDB (from your call to ImageMatrixDB::load) to a List<ImageMatrix>, for which there is no available conversion. It also strikes me as a bit odd, how you are using the load function, it seems as though you are using it like some sort of factory. You are currently loading in both training and validation data in to the same list.

Comment: Regarding loading them into the same list I must have completely overlooked that, thanks. Regarding the other issue is there any work around you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have designed your class, it should be used as follows:

```
ImageMatrixDB trainingSet = new ImageMatrixDB();
ImageMatrixDB validationSet = new ImageMatrixDB();
trainingSet.load("cw2DataSet1.csv");
validationSet.load("cw2DataSet2.csv");
```

Note the two instances of ImageMatrixDB rather than the one, which ensures that the training / validation data are loaded in to different lists.

A quick side note, when calculating distances in kNN, you should be able to get away with using the squared distance (efficiency gain, sqrt is an expensive operation). So `return (int)Math.sqrt(sum);` should not require the square root.

Comment: perfect thanks. One issue, its now not recognising .size() from the java.util.*, any ideas?

Comment: You will need to write a function on ImageMatrixDB for this, which calls .size() of its internal list.

Comment: So have the list as the argument and just apply .size() within the function ?

Comment: No, you will have a function within ImageMatrixDB, `public int size() { return list.size(); }`. I suggest you run through some java tutorials at some point, a lot of this stuff is relatively straight forward once you have the basics down.